# Create layout avoiding overlapping floating wrapfigures

Tags: beamer, positioning, minipage, wrapfigure

I'm writing companion notes for some beamer presentations. For each slide in a presentation, the document has a small picture of the slide, along with a text explaining the slide. For some slides, the text will be long, while for others, it may be just a sentence or no text at all.

I'd like the layout to be something like this:

[image: Layout]

Each slide is inside a `wrapfigure` environment. The problem I have is that, when there is not enough text to wrap around the slide, the slide and the next one will overlap. I tried putting every slide+text into a `minipage`, but this doesn't solve the problem.

For an example, see page 2 of [this document](http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://csrg.inf.utfsm.cl/~rbonvall/01-notas.pdf). The code is in https://gist.github.com/830055

How can I avoid floating figures to overlap, so each slide appears in the right place?

Can you think of a better way to create a layout like this one?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a way to automate this, but you can manually specify a height for the minipages that have very little text in them:

```
\begin{minipage}[t][2.75in]{\textwidth}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{.50\textwidth}
      \fbox{\includeslide[width=.45\textwidth]{evaluaciones}}
    \end{wrapfigure}

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc convallis
    erat eu nunc commodo feugiat. 
  \end{minipage}
```

Answer (score 1):

The example is difficult to use without having the slides...

However, you might get away by using the optional argument of wrapfigure

```
\begin{wrapfigure}[10]{r}{5cm}
```

The [10] is the number of shortened lines.